# SQL Server Bulk Copy dynamic script

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

I've quite a bunch of CSV files I would like to import into a SQL Server database. Each of these files contain over 50 million rows which I need to import into a single table called `ControlExperimentTable`.

A total of 500 of these files will be sent to me over the next few weeks to import into the database, so I wrote a script to automate the process it is obviously long and cumbersome.

In a nutshell, the process works as follows -- CSV files are copied into a repository folder for processing. All files have the same prefix and a unique suffix e.g `ExportData0001.txt`, `ExportData0002.txt`, `ExportData0003.txt`, `ExportData0004.txt`, etc.

The script sequentially processes each file, importing its contents into the SQL Server database. After all rows have been imported, the processed file is then moved to an archive folder, a full database backup is taken and the process moves on to the next file.

The following is the code I'm using to accomplish the task:

```
--Int variable declaration section.
DECLARE @totalFilesToProcess INT = 500  /*The number of files in the repository.*/
DECLARE @count INT = 0

--VarChar variable declaration section.
DECLARE @sqlBulkInsertCommand VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @sqlMoveCommand VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @sourceFilename VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @errorFilename VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @suffix VARCHAR(4)

--Ensure that the xp_cmdshell server configuration option is enabled.
EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE

EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
RECONFIGURE

--Change to the target database instance.
USE [DataCollectionTable]

--Set the script to loop the number of times as there are as may files to import
WHILE (@count <= @totalFilesToProcess)
BEGIN
    --Set variables.
    SET @count = @count + 1
    SET @suffix = RIGHT('0000' + CAST(@count AS VARCHAR(4)), 4)
    SET @errorFilename = FORMATMESSAGE('E:\SharedDocs\ControlExportData%s.csv', @suffix)
    SET @sourceFilename = FORMATMESSAGE('E:\SharedDocs\ControlExportData%s.txt', @suffix)
    
    --COMMAND CONSTRUCT: Insert data from flat file into the ControlExperimentTable table.
    SET @sqlBulkInsertCommand = FORMATMESSAGE('BULK INSERT ControlExperimentTable FROM ''%s'' WITH (FIRSTROW = 2,   FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'', ERRORFILE = ''%s'', TABLOCK)', @sourceFilename, @errorFilename)
    
    --COMMAND CONSTRUCT: Move the source file to the archive folder.
    SET @sqlMoveCommand = FORMATMESSAGE('MOVE E:\SharedDocs\ControlExportData%s.txt E:\SharedDocs\Archive\ControlExportData%s.txt', @suffix, @suffix)
    
    --Display record count before every update.
    SELECT sys.sysindexes.rows FROM sys.sysindexes INNER JOIN sys.sysobjects 
    ON sys.sysobjects.id=sys.sysindexes.id 
    WHERE sys.sysindexes.first IS NOT NULL AND sys.sysobjects.name = 'ControlExperimentTable'
    
    --Execute the BULK INSERT command.
    EXEC @sqlBulkInsertCommand

    --Execute the source file MOVE command.
    EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @sqlMoveCommand 
    
    --Backup database after each commitment, maintaining the current and previous copies.
    IF (@count % 2)  = 0
    BEGIN
        BACKUP DATABASE [ExperimentDataCollection] TO DISK = N'E:\Backups\ExperimentDataCollectionBackup-01.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, INIT, NAME = N'ExperimentDataCollection-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10
    END ELSE
    BEGIN 
        BACKUP DATABASE [ExperimentDataCollection] TO DISK = N'E:\Backups\ExperimentDataCollectionBackup-02.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, INIT, NAME = N'ExperimentDataCollection-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10
    END
END
```

After running this code, I'm getting the following error:

> Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
> Configuration option 'xp_cmdshell' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
>
> Msg 911, Level 16, State 4, Line 48
> Database 'BULK INSERT ControlExperimentTable FROM 'E:\SharedDocs\ExportData0001' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
>
> Completion time: 2021-02-18T18:06:15.0003210+02:00

Mind you, everything is where they are supposed to be and correctly specified in the code. So much so that manually running the following code, which is exactly what I'm trying to parse works without a hassle.

```
USE [ExperimentDataCollection]

BULK INSERT [ExperimentDataCollection].[dbo].[ControlExperimentTable] 
FROM 'E:\SharedDocs\ControlExportData0001.txt' 
WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, 
      FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
      ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', 
      ERRORFILE = 'E:\SharedDocs\ControlExportData0001.csv', 
      TABLOCK)
```

Where is it I'm going wrong?

Comment: Your error has a file name with no extension after your FROM.  Shouldnt that have extension?

Comment: Your variable declaration is only `varchar(255)` so the command is truncated. Try `nvarchar(MAX)`.

Comment: I would really, really do this from Powershell, using the `bcp` command to do the Bulk Insert. T-SQL is not the place for file manipulation and dynamic bulk inserts

Comment: @Brad, I saw that and did `SELECT` on the `@sqlBulkInsertCommand` just to make sure it was being parsed correctly.  It was indeed.

Comment: @DanGuzman, thanks for pointing that out. It would have definitely caused a problem in future. However, in this case I was only 62 characters from getting a truncation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When executing dynamic sql, you need to wrap the variable in parentheses.  So change this:

```
EXEC @sqlBulkInsertCommand
```

to this:

```
EXEC(@sqlBulkInsertCommand)
```

Comment: Just like that! Worked like a charm!